# Mobile connectivity in Budapest subway

Tags: public-transport, cellphones, budapest

Is there mobile networks coverage in Budapest underground? If yes, is it good enough to use mobile internet? (And not just on stations, but also in the tunnels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [pnuts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4995/pnuts) gave comment, that I want to promote to answer:

> [The network [Vodafone], which covers both subway stations as well as tunnels, supports download speeds of up to 21.6 Mbps](http://www.telecompaper.com/news/vodafone-hungary-offers-mobile-internet-in-budapest-subway--844399)